# Ruby Date Time versus PHP Date Time

Tags: php, ruby, datetime

I have the following code in PHP, I am trying to write the same in Ruby.

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));  
$created = $date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); //YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z;
```

Where T stands for Timezone Abbreviation and Z stands for Timezone Offset in PHP (Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
The sample date generated by this is `2012-09-20T15:46:22.571Z`

The ruby code that I have come up with is `Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%Z%H:%M:%S")` but it gives the output `2012-09-20UTC00:24:57` which is close to what I am trying to get to but not exactly the same. Can anyone point me to the right direction in order to get the part with .xxxZ in the end?

Comment: I have come up with `Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")` but not sure if thats the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a better look at [Time#strftime Various ISO 8601 formats section](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) and probably you will come up with:

```
Time.now.strftime("%F%Z%T.%LZ")
```

1. `%F` For The ISO 8601 date format (%Y-%m-%d)
2. `%Z` For Time zone abbreviation name
3. `%T.%L` For Local time with decimal fraction, full stop as decimal sign (extended)
4. `Z` For the final `"Z"` in time string.